# Mageplaza Magento 2 brazil language pack is not working

Tags: magento2, localisation, magento2.2.6

```
composer require mageplaza/magento-2-portuguese-brazil-language-pack:dev-master
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_BR
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I ran those commands language appear in admin dashboard, I have selected the desired language `Store->Configuration->General-> locale`
After that i have tried removing `var/cache , var/view_preprocessed , generated , pub/static` ... but nothing impacts on my site. 
[image]
[image]

What I am doing wrong I am not getting it.

Comment: yes ofcourse i did

Comment: as I see, it should work.

Comment: yes it should but there might be something we should do to get the desired result ... i am missing something maybe

Comment: could you see the package under vendor folder? `mageplaza/magento-2-portuguese-brazil-language-pack:dev-master`

Comment: yes there is a folder with the same name except :dev-master

Comment: I think it is working but not in case of every thing

Comment: some of the things is in portugese